# How do i call Post method of HttpServlet from GWT servlet?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I have two servlets, one is a `GWT` Servlet which extends `RemoteServiceServlet` and second is BasicServlet which extends `HttpServlet`. So my question is how do i call post method of `HttpServlet` from `GWT Servlet`. And here I confirm, I don't want to redirect to servlet using `RequestDispatcher`, I want to create a new Post call with new parameters.

Please guide me in right direction.

TIA!!!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an odd thing to do. Can't you put the code you want to execute in a third class/service and call it directly?

If they are on different servers (or some other reason) then you could use HttpClient (or similar)?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I made it work by merging the code into `GWT` servlet.